# Check if a file is empty or not

Tags: c

How can I check if a text file has something written or not. I tried:

```
LOGIC checkfile(char * filename)
{
    FILE *pf;
    pf=fopen(filename,"wt");
    fseek(pf,0,SEEK_END);
    if(ftell(pf)==0)
    printf("empty");
}
```

This function returns empty everytime, even in my text file I have few words or numbers written.

Comment: Don't open the file for writing - that truncates the file to length zero.   Open it for reading (which won't change the file size).   Preferably in binary mode, if you are using `fseek()` and `ftell()`..   Once a file is open for reading, call `fgetc()` once - if it succeeds, the file has some content.   Also remember to close the file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you opened the file for writing. When you do that, everything in the file is lost, and the length of the file is truncated to 0.

So you need to open the file for reading. And the easiest way to see if the file is empty is to try to read the first character with `fgetc`. If `fgetc` returns EOF, then the file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: **DO NOT OPEN THE FILE FOR WRITING!**
second: for knowing about file status in C you can use [fstat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html) which is in sys headear file!

You can use **struct stat** for using this function
here is a simple example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    int fields = 0; 
    int size = 0; 

    // Open the file test.txt through open() 
    // Note that since the call to open directly gives 
    // integer file descriptor so we used open here. 
    // One can also use fopen() that returns FILE* 
    // object. Use fileno() in that case to convert 
    // FILE* object into the integer file descriptor 
    if(fields = open(file_path, "r")){
        struct stat buf;
        fstat(fields, &buf);
        size = (int)buf.st_size;
    }

    printf("size of file is %d", size);

   return 0;
   }
```

**Note**: I just include a header file that related to fstat. You can add other header files yourself

Answer (score 1):

What about using `fscanf` to read the file, and check if something was actually read?

```
FILE *fp;
char buff[255] = "";

fp = fopen(filename, "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
if (!*buff)
    printf("Empty\n");
else
    printf("%s\n", buff);
fclose(fp);
```